# Wifi scanning tool

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, scanning

Few days ago I bought wifi usb adapter for extended range reasons. it was installed properly on my macbook pro with mavericks. As results I can use it to connect on-line. I'd like to use Wifi Scanner application to gather more informations about hot spots around me. The problem is that Wifi Scanner recognizes only en0 interface that correspond to Wifi internal mac interface. The wifi usb external adapter isn't recognized. how can I do? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No I haven't tried it yet...but I have found some interesting infos about the problems. Developers of WiFi Explorer, a very similar applications to WiFi Scanner, say they use CoreWLan. This is what they say: Apple's official framework for Wi-Fi scanning, CoreWLAN, seems to support only certain type of wireless adapters. Most of the USB wireless adapters cannot be recognized by the framework and will not work with WiFi Explorer, but others may work just fine.

Comment: Have you selected a specific WiFi scanner and want to see how it can support your chosen hardware or are you looking for suggested software that works with USB wifi dongles in general? Please edit your question so that people can assist you more directly with some options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Kismac](http://kismac-ng.org) does what you need. It’s a port of [Kismet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kismet_%28software%29) for OS X. Unfortunately, the current build is three years old, so it might not run perfectly on a newer OS or newer material.